# Ion-input disabled opacity

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, input, opacity

I have a problem with my ion-input when I deactivate it, it has an opacity that I want to modify, however by inspecting the element, I see that the ion-input contains an input with an opacity of .4 and I cannot access it despite several attempts in the css.
So I'm looking for a solution if someone has this, thank you

Comment: Try to put "!important" when overrideing the css class

Comment: I did, but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the 'readonly' property to conturn the problem